# General solution of second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on finding the general solution of a differential equation. But I'm not getting too far. This is a question from my exam papers, can someone work it out, with simple steps so I can understand it, please.

[image: question]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1) find a general solution of the homogeneous problem ($y'' -4y' +4y = 0$)

Step 2) apply the "variation of constant" formula to find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous problem.

Step 3) [what you have found in step 1)] + [what you have found in step 2)]

Have you tried this approach?

**EDIT**:
As you checked $y(t) = c_1e^{2t} + c_2te^{2t}$ is the general solution you have to find in step 1).

**Theorem:** Let $y(t) = \int_{t_0}^t Y(t - s)f(s)\ ds$, where $Y(t)$ is the solution of the problem

$$Y'' +aY' + bY = 0$$
$$Y(0) = 0,\ Y'(0) = 1.$$
Then $y(t)$ is a solution of the equation $y'' + ay' + by = f(t)$. Moreover, it is the only solution such that $y(t_0) = y'(t_0) = 0$.

The proof is very easy because you are just asked to calculate the derivatives of $y(t)$ as it is defined and substitute in the equation keeping in mind that $Y$ is the solution of a known problem.

We are going to apply this to your problem!
Let's find $Y$!
It is the solution of
$$Y'' - 4Y' + 4Y = 0$$
$$Y(0) = 0,\ Y'(0) = 1.$$

Therefore $Y(t) = c_1e^{2t} + c_2te^{2t}$, where
$$0 = Y(0) = c_1$$
$$1 = Y'(0) = 2c_2.$$
This gives $Y(t) = \frac{t}{2}e^{2t}$.

According with the theorem above a solutin of the inhomogeneous problem is
$$y(t) = \int_{t_0}^t Y(t - s)f(s)\ ds = \int_{t_0}^t \frac{(t - s)}{2}e^{2(t - s)}se^{5s}\ ds.$$

This ends spep 2)

Then, the general solution of your equation is 
$$y(t) = c_1e^{2t} + c_2te^{2t} + \int_{t_0}^t \frac{(t - s)}{2}e^{2(t - s)}se^{5s}\ ds.$$

You can of course calculate the last integral. You can also choose $t_0 = 0$ if you wish so. A particular choise for $t_0$ is required only when you have to impose cauchy's conditions.

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yes, I get the roots of the equation by doing step 1.
But what is step two?

Comment: perfect, I am going to edit with a more detailed solution :D

Comment: I edited with the solution. I was too lazy to evaluate the integral, in the final formula, I hope you can forgive me!